# RST ACK after SYN and Retransmission

Tags: tcp, wireshark, rst

I'm very new with network, so forgive me if I ask dumb questions or if my vocabulary is bad

I'm trying to access an URL from a partner on a specific port. The server has a firewall which only accepts allowed IP address

The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes not. I checked with Wireshark what the problem was and we receive a RST - ACK after a few TCP Retransmission

[image: Wireshark Error]

Before asking our partner to check their servers, I'd like to make sure that the issue is not caused by something we do wrong

**What could be the cause of this error ?**

Let me know if you need more informations

Answer (score 1):

When a connection is not ended correctly the TCP Reset flag is set to 1. However Windows and some OS us this flag together with ACK to mean a graceful disconnection and not a problem.

I would suggest to use the Wireshark filter **tcp.flags.reset==1 && tcp.flags.ack == 0** to get only resets without ACK.

On the server side you may want to look to the percentages of communication errors you have in your trace :

- Normal < 5%
- Minor problems 5~10%
- Serious problems >10

Using the overall filter : **tcp.analysis.flags && !tcp.analysis.window_update**

Or more in depth with the following flags :

> tcp.analysis.flags && !tcp.analysis.window_update
>
> tcp.analysis.retransmission
>
> tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack
>
> tcp.analysis.out_of_order
>
> tcp.analysis.zero_window
>
> tcp.analysis.window_full

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the down-vote? Because if I'm wrong I would like to understand why to learn from it. Thx